# Trying to Loop through variable in Toad

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to have some code read through 800k lines of data to only show me certain results that will then be grouped and then cycle through the data again and create another group based on a new variable.

Example of what I need:

1 - Group all transactions that have department 100 sold in them and name that group 100
2 - Group all transactions that have department 101 sold in them and name that group 101

ETC, I need to do this for 7 departments.  Below is my code that I feel like I'm close to getting right.

I believe my declare may be wrong, as it looks to be only allowing 30 rows to be returned but maybe someone can confirm that for me?

---

```
DECLARE
    DEPT_LOOP number(3) := 100;

BEGIN
    WHILE DEPT_LOOP < 130 LOOP

        SELECT DEPT_LOOP, MARKET_BASKET_ITM2.*
        INTO   DEPT_LOOP, MARKET_BASKET_ITM2.*
        FROM   ( SELECT MARKET_BASKET_ITM2.ORDER_KEY
                 FROM   JBINGEL.MARKET_BASKET_ITM2 MARKET_BASKET_ITM2
                 WHERE  (MARKET_BASKET_ITM2.DEPARTMENT_ID = DEPT_LOOP)
                 GROUP BY MARKET_BASKET_ITM2.ORDER_KEY ) subquery,
               JBINGEL.MARKET_BASKET_ITM2 MARKET_BASKET_ITM2
        WHERE  (subquery.ORDER_KEY = MARKET_BASKET_ITM2.ORDER_KEY);

        DEPT_LOOP := DEPT_LOOP + 1;

    END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Yes, your loop runs from `dept_loop = 100` to `dept_loop < 130`, which is 30 iterations. Where are the 800k rows you mentioned? (And does TOAD actually have anything to do with it?)

Comment: Hi, I have to run this data through Toad, I was told that the Toad syntax may be different. (VBA seemed much easier to cycle/loop through).   As far as the data, I have a table called MARKET_BASKET_ITM2 that houses the 820k lines of data that I'm sifting through.   We actually have only 17 departments but they're spaced between 100 and 130, which is why I had that range built out.  Hopefully that helps?  Let me know if I can explain better, thanks.

Comment: TOAD doesn't have a syntax, it's just a desktop application for working with Oracle databases. The code you posted is written in PL/SQL. Regarding your loop, you should probably start by just writing a plain SQL query that does the grouping you need using a `group by` clause.